# ERROR_UNKNOWN downloading file from Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-storage

Im trying to download a file *.Apk from the storage and install when is completed.
i revised the rules from storage and the uses.

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read : if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

on rules monitor all operations are accepted but the file can't be donwloaded

fragment of donwload code is:

```
public void downloadUpdate() {
    StorageReference gsReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance("filename.apk");
    final String rutadestino = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/";
    final String nombrearchivo = "LeaderBoard-Upd.apk";
    final Uri archivodestino = Uri.parse("file://" + rutadestino+nombrearchivo);
    File localFile = new File(rutadestino+nombrearchivo);
    if (localFile.exists()) {
        localFile.delete();
    }

    gsReference.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
             //Local temp file has been created
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", new File(rutadestino+nombrearchivo));
                Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                install.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                install.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                install.setData(contentUri);
                startActivity(install);
                //unregisterReceiver(this);
                finish();
            } else {
                Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                install.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                install.setDataAndType(archivodestino,
                        "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                startActivity(install);
                //unregisterReceiver(this);
                finish();
            }
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle any errors
            int errorCode = ((StorageException) exception).getErrorCode();
            String errorMessage = exception.getMessage();
            Emergente.ErrorCode(1,getApplicationContext());
        }
    });
}
```

i received
errorcode "13000"
errorMessage "An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response."
cause "open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)"

Maybe another code fragment is wrong, but in this momment im stucked on the OnFailureListener

Comment: You are looking for a URL formed like: 
`http://storage.googleapis.com/<bucket>/<object>`

you can see more info on the [GCS docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#rest-download-object). also be carefull when positng the complete URL since it might be dangerous.

Comment: sorry i confused the storage provider. but the problem is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on the app permissions, when app tries to download files and write it on a wrong directory/file without the required permission it will trow the "ERROR_UNKNOWN" message.

The solution is create the file on the same app directory, when doing so the permission is not required unles the API <= 18 then the permission will be necessary.

Solution:

```
File localFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "file.apk");
```